# java how replace a char at a set index with a string

Tags: java, string, replace, char

Hi I need to be able to replace one character with a string at a set index.

Example:

```
"hello ? would you like a ? from ?"
```

this is the method I would like to use:

```
query.bindValue(0,"Mr Boo");
query.bindValue(1,"cake");
query.bindValue(2,"Mr Foo");
```

output I would like :

```
"hello Mr Boo would you like a cake from Mr Foo"
```

I need to put it in any order and it will be the same result:

```
query.bindValue(2,"Mr Foo");
query.bindValue(0,"Mr Boo");
query.bindValue(1,"cake");
```

ANSWER:

```
public class DBQuery {

private String querystr;

Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();

public void prepare(String str){
    this.querystr = str;
}

public void bindValue(int num, String value){
    map.put(num, value);
}

public void execute(){

    java.util.List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet()); 
    Collections.sort(keys);

    for(Integer key : keys){
        querystr = querystr.replaceFirst("\\?", map.get(key));
    }

    System.out.println(querystr);
}
}
```

Comment: Is it for a sql query?! You can use `PreparedStatement` for this in that case.

Comment: have you already tried?

Comment: Try to alter your question to ask what you really want. Avoid the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: I am building my own query mechanic for a custom database system so am not using mysql so the preparedstatement wont fit my needs

Comment: Are there any cases where `?` should be literal and not metacharacter that should be replaced?

Comment: Please do not put the answer in the question. You can either add your own answer or accept an existing answer which solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this using a `Map` and `regex` as follows:

```
Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>(); //this map contains the values
map.put(3, "Mr Foo");
map.put(0, "Mr Boo");
map.put(1, "cake");
map.put(2, "cookie");

String query = "hello ? would you like a ? or a ? from ?"; //this is the query

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\?").matcher(query);
int index = 0;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(matcher.find()){ 
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, map.get(index));
    index++;
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString()); // this will display the query as you want
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I used your code and had done my answer for it.

Comment: @user2716281 not so fast. I didn't realize if you do for instance `map.put(0, "What happened?")` then this method doesn't work properly. See updated answer that fixes this mistake.

Answer (score 4):

This will convert your input string to the desired output:

```
str = String.format(str.replace("?", "%s"), "Mr Boo", "cake", "Mr Foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem if you have a method that find the nth `?` in a String and replce it for a word. For instance the 2nd `?` `(id = 1)` you will replace by "cake", and when you want to catch the 3rd `?` `(id = 2)`, and since the 2nd `?` is already replaced by cake, this will be now the "new" 2nd and not the 3rd.

Thus, the best way is to split your query by the `?` into `String Array`, make it `static` and if you wanto do bind `id = 1`, pick the `array[1]` and append the string you want, if you want the `id=n` pick `array[n]` and append your string..

in the end, append all elements of your array and the query is complete.

something like

```
static String[] arrayQuery =  "hello ? would you like a ? from ?".split("?");

public void fillQuery(int position, String word) {
   arrayQuery[position] = arrayQuery[position]+word);
}
```

in the end, to return the query, iterate over the array and return one `String` with all elements